# open webservices calls not responded caused the server to crash

Tags: asp.net, networking, server

We have a site hosted on our local server.
everything was fine untill we had to get info via webservices from another external server that doesnt belong to us.

Each user on our site now generates at least 4 WS calls on every single page.

We set the timeout of ws response to 5 sec, and that worked for the first period, what happend lately is that the external server that need to respond to the webservices is very slow, and responding after 1min or never.

As a result our server are opening 100+ connections in a minute and chocking...

Is there a way to limit number of open ws connections?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know this its not possible to limit max number of connections, assuming you are using Windows server.